# python pyqt4 closeEvent preventing windows restart/shutdown?

Tags: python, pyqt4

i added closeEvent in my application to prevent the user from pressing alt-f4 and closing the application.My problem now is when i shutdown or restart the computer manually in the start menu, nothing happens.

```
def closeEvent(self, event):    
    event.ignore()
```

i also try this code but it didn't proceed to the if TRUE statement.

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
         if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_F4 and (event.modifiers() &
         QtCore.Qt.AltModifier):
                  print 'do something'
```

Comment: @unice Which OS are you using?

Comment: You can't trap system shortcuts like `Alt+F4` and `Ctrl+Alt+Del` with `keyPressEvent`, `event`, etc. The close event will happen before the key press event is completed. But do you _really_ need to completely prevent the user closing the window? Why not just show a confirmation dialog?

Comment: Its for security reason. The application should not be closed and can only be controlled remotely by another computer, that's why I'm not having a problem in shutdown/restarting remotely by force termination

Comment: Sounds like you're writing a virus or malware

Answer (score 0):

Could you make use of [QApplication.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop)?

When set to `False`, this will keep the application alive when the top-level window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to prevent the system from shutting down, or allow it to shutdown, but you should have a look at `QApplication.commitData` which is normally called when the system is shutting down, and `QSessionManager`

You could for example set a flag in commitData to help differentiate between a normal close event that you should ignore and one that is due to the system in the `closeEvent` function.